# Error al calcular nuevas filas con función mutate del paquete tidyverse en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, r-dplyr, tidyverse

Tengo que evaluar la efectividad de un tratamiento hormonal (auxinas) en plantas frente a un testigo. Evaluamos cada semana varios parámetros como altura del tallo, área foliar, etc. con 3 repeticiones por tratamiento (Hormonas y testigo). La cuestión es que tenemos que analizar varios índices ([fórmulas de los índices](https://i.postimg.cc/0QNSm6pH/image.png)) y luego hacer una gráfica de cada variable a través del tiempo para cada tratamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, se tienen que calcular los índices, no es un valor que se tome en laboratorio, por ello trato de añadirlos a mi dataframe con la función mutate, sin embargo no me realiza el cálculo y me arroja solo valores NA.

Así se ve mi dataframe cargado y ordenado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es evaluar estos índices para cada repetición para poder obtener 3 valores por semana y que las gráficas tengan valores de varianza o desviación y queden como la que mostré anteriormente (realizarlo con la media no me sirve ya que no existiría ninguna desviación)

Este es mi código

```
data_ind <- dataf %>% select(Tratamiento, Semana, Repeticion, Masa_hojas, Masa_tallo, Masa_raiz, Area_foliar)%>%
                  group_by(Tratamiento, Semana, Repeticion) %>%
                  arrange(Tratamiento, Repeticion) %>%
                  mutate(Peso_total = Masa_hojas+Masa_tallo+Masa_raiz) %>%
                  mutate(Tasa_crecimiento = (( log(Peso_total) - log( lag(Peso_total) ) ) / ( Semana - lag(Semana) ) ) ) %>%
                  mutate(Tasa_asimilacion = (  ( (Peso_total-lag(Peso_total) )/( Semana-lag(Semana)) ) * ( ( (log(Area_foliar)) - (log( lag(Area_foliar) )) ) / ( Area_foliar-lag(Area_foliar)) )  )) %>%
                  mutate(Relacion_AF = ( ( ( lag(Area_foliar)/lag(Peso_total) )+( Area_foliar/Peso_total ) )/2 ) ) %>%
                  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))
```

Lo que hago es crear un nuevo dataframe (`data_ind`) que contiene los índices, selecciono con `select` las columnas solamente necesarias para realizar los cálculos (solamente se va a realizar TRC, TAN y RAF, ver el link de los índices).

Luego los agrupo y ordeno (con `group_by` y `arrange`) para que los cálculos se realicen correctamente, ya que son formulas que sus cálculos dependen del valor de la semana actual y de la semana anterior, por tanto lo ordené para que las repeticiones estuvieran ordenadas por semana y a su vez estas estuvieran ordenadas por tratamiento (después de esto es como me queda en la imagen que mostré del dataframe ordenado).

El problema viene cuando uso `mutate`, para generar nuevas columnas con las fórmulas, la del peso total no hay problema y se genera correctamene, pero el resto me generan valores `NA` y con la línea final de mi código se convierten en 0. Muestro captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver el peso total se calcula perfectamente, pero el resto son 0, T-T.
Esto no pasaba antes de agrupar y ordenar el dataframe, pero después me percaté que si no lo ordenaba los índices no estaban correctamente calculados ya que dependen del tiempo. No se me ocurre más, ¿tal vez hacer cálculos con una variable agrupada?

Comment: ¿Está bien agrupar por `Repeticion`? Me da la impresión que terminas con grupos de una sola fila, lo cual hace que `lag(log(Peso_total))`  sea `NA` y termine invalidando el calculo.

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, el problema fue la agrupacion, ya intuia que podia ir por ahi pero no saba exactamente como arreglarlo, era una simple linea de codigo @.@ Muchsiimas gracias

Comment: @GUSTAVOADOLFOARANGOACOSTA quizá puedas agregar como respuesta la solución a tu problema y/o editar tu pregunta con tu solución, esto para posteriores.